# Get headers with executeOperation on Apollo Server (apollo-server) for integrations tests

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Since the deprecation of `apollo-server-testing` I am using the new way of doing integration tests with apollo-server (included in apollo-server 2.25.0). From the mutation ***signin*** I set my refresh token in the OutgoingMessage header's (in `'Set-Cookie'`).

### Simplified resolver

```js
    @Mutation(() => RefreshTokenOutput)
    async refreshToken(@Ctx() { response, contextRefreshToken }: Context): Promise<RefreshTokenOutput> {
        if (contextRefreshToken) {
            const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await this.authService.refreshToken(contextRefreshToken);
            response.setHeader(
                'Set-Cookie',
                cookie.serialize('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    maxAge: maxAge,
                    secure: true,
                })
            );
            return { accessToken: accessToken };
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationError();
        }
    }
```

### Test case

```js
            // given:
            const { user, clearPassword } = await userLoader.createUser16c();
            const input = new UserSigninInput();
            input.email = user.email;
            input.password = clearPassword;

            const MUTATE_signin = gql`
                mutation signin($userInput: UserSigninInput!) {
                    signin(input: $userInput) {
                        accessToken
                    }
                }
            `;

            // when:
            const res = await server.executeOperation(
                { query: MUTATE_signin, variables: { userInput: input }, operationName: 'signin' },
                buildContext(user)
            );
```

I'm trying to test if this token is correctly set and well formed. Did you have any idea on how I can access this header with `executeOperation` ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set headers like this:

```
const res = await apolloServer.executeOperation({ query: chicken, variables: { id: 1 } }, {req: {headers: 'Authorization sdf'}});
```

Comment: Do u mean `request`? req is not a known property.

Comment: Hmm maybe `req` is from a different version. Make sure you have the exact bracket structure as me.

Answer (score 0):

server.executeOperation calls processGraphQLRequest

and processGraphQLRequest return type is GraphQLResponse

```
export interface GraphQLResponse {
  data?: Record<string, any> | null;
  errors?: ReadonlyArray<GraphQLFormattedError>;
  extensions?: Record<string, any>;
  http?: Pick<Response, 'headers'> & Partial<Pick<Mutable<Response>, 'status'>>;
}
```

I'm not sure, but i think headers in GraphQLResponse.http

you can find call structure in github repo.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/6b9c2a0f1932e6d8fb94a8662cc1da24980aec6f/packages/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts#L126

Comment: I have setten up a quick repo to reproduce the actual problem. ( https://github.com/Sakdow/basic-appolo-server-project ).

Here `res.http?.headers` doesn't seems to have the cookie that I have set in my mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Apollo defines `executeOperation` as:

```
  public async executeOperation(
    request: Omit<GraphQLRequest, 'query'> & {
      query?: string | DocumentNode;
    },
    integrationContextArgument?: ContextFunctionParams,
  ) {
```

`integrationContextArgument` is optional and `ContextFunctionParams` is just an alias to `any`.
As mentioned in an answer above, any context JSON passed to the `executeOperation` function will be sent to Apollo's `processGraphQLRequest()` function

`graphQLServerOptions()` function processes that JSON.
For more advanced scenarios, it seems that a context resolver function, not just JSON context data, can be passed in using the `context` field

Reference: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/e9ae0f28d11d2fdfc5abd5048c85acf70de21592/packages/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts#L1014